# Error: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined when Using Ionic Routing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an ionic application. In Which my app component's HTML looks like this.

```
<ion-header>
    // some header related code here
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-nav class="outline" [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <footer-component></footer-component>
</ion-footer>
```

in my footer component, I have a button which sends my application to start page, whenever clicked. following is the component in which a function pushtoStartPage is called when tap on that button -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'footer-component',
  templateUrl: 'footer.html'
})
export class FooterComponent {

  text: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }


  pushtoStartPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push('StartPage');
  }

}
```

Whenever i Tap on that button I get this error - **Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined**. can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like an issue due to your footer component is out of your navigation stack. To use routing you have to get the Rootnav. Which you can get from App instance.

You can use something like this -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { App } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'footer-component',
  templateUrl: 'footer.html'
})
export class FooterComponent {

  text: string;

  constructor(private app: App) {
  }


  pushtoStartPage() {
    this.app.getRootNav().push('StartPage');
  }

}
```

**and do Remove NavController from your component.**